# Electromagnetic Waves as Voltage Signals

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, voltage

The text says :

The source connected to the transmission line’s sending end may be any circuit generating an output voltage, such as a radar transmitter, an amplifier, or a computer terminal operating in transmission mode.

Doesn't radar emit EM waves and not voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every voltage is associated with an electric field by

$$V_{ab}=\int_a^b\vec{E}\cdot{\rm d}\ell$$

where $a$ and $b$ are two points in space and $V_{ab}$ is the voltage between $a$ and $b$.

But this integral only has a well-defined value in the electrostatic limit, meaning when the electric and magnetic fields in the region are not changing. When we analyze *lumped circuits* with AC or time-varying voltages, we are only making an approximation of their behavior, but it can be a very good approximation.

So when we apply a voltage between two electrodes, we produce an electric field between those electrodes. Or if we apply a voltage to an antenna, we produce an electric field between the antenna and the other terminal of our voltage source (which we can connect to earth).

If we apply an AC voltage to an antenna, we can stimulate an electromagnetic wave to be radiated by that antenna.

But once that wave is propagating in space, the electrostatic potential (voltage) concept is not adequate to describe its behavior because the time-varying magnetic component of the wave is significant.

> Doesn't radar emit EM waves and not voltage?

Yes, a radar transmitter emits EM waves. But it is possible to drive this emission using a circuit analyzed as a lumped circuit with voltages and currents.

*Note:* Antenna engineers extend the concept of potential with the [vector potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_potential#Magnetic_vector_potential) to enable analyzing many wave propagation phenomena beyond what the electrostatic potential can describe.

Comment: So basically we are modeling the real case of emitting waves and receiving ways using circuit models to simplify and approximate the work and calculation .

Comment: @Hasan, yes, whenever we talk about voltage we're actually using a simplified model of a physical situation that actually involves fields and waves.

Comment: Speaking about the real case not simplification . Can we say the EM waves travel in the electromagnetic field created by the physical current passing in the wires ( Assuming transmission in real wires not in other mediums )

Comment: I wouldn't say the field is created by the current. It's equally valid to say the current is created by the field, and IMO even more correct to say that neither can exist without the other.

Comment: I agree with what you said , but does the em "wave" travel in the em "field " present in the wire.

Comment: The field is (mainly) around the wire, not in the wire.